# POST asp.net form username and password to an external HTTPS login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net c#. I have created a login form that when the user submits will POST their username and password to a secure external login form outside of my application. I tried doing this by setting up a httprequest but it did not work. What is the best way of doing this with c# in asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple example. I hope this is what you need:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var result = webClient.UploadString("https://your-url.com", string.Format("username={0}password={1}", "usernamegoeshere", "paswordgoeshere"));
}
```